# React cannot assign class field outside axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios

```
class App extends React.Component {
  app: Application;

  ...
  componentDidMound() {
    axios.get(…).then(res => {
        this.app.currentUser = res.data.data; // value assigned here.
        console.log(this.app.currentUser); // and print the current user object.
    };
    console.log(this.app.currentUser); // but here print currentUser = undefined.
  }
}
```

Why this.app.currentUser assigned in lambda but not outside?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using Axios it will create a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). The `.then` is occuring after (when the promise resolves) the `console.log` which is outside the axios `.then`.

Also, for what it's worth, setting values like you are is an antipattern.

Here's how I would change your code:

```
class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        currentUser: "" // <-- making an assumption that the response is just a string.
    }

    componentDidMount() { // <-- note the actual spelling
        axios.get("http://example.com/").then(res => {
            this.setState({
                currentUser: res.data.data
            });
        });
    }

    render() {
        const { currentUser } = this.state;
        // On initial render currentUser will be an empty string. Once the axios call resolves the setState will be called
        // and it will re-render with the new data.
        return (
            <div>{currentUser}</div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't hard to understand, `axios.get` is an async function, so `console.log` be invoked before `axios.get`.

Consider:

`|
|\_____________
console.log   |
|           axios.get
|             |
\     ???     /`

You can not know which one will be invoked first. Usually isn't `axios.get` here.
If you want to print data, put `console.log` into callback.

Comment: i just want to load current user in App component.

Comment: Doesn't matter, the point is wait `axios.get` done.